# How to remove ?___store= from hreflang url?

Tags: hreflang

```
<?php foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            $storeCode = $store->getCode();
            echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $storeCode . '" href="' . $store->getCurrentUrl(false) . '"/>' . "\n";
        }
    } } ?>
```

This produces, for example,

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en_ca" href="http://mywebsite.com/en/?___store=en_ca">
```

But I want to remove `?___store=en_ca` part.

I tried replacing:

```
$this->_href = $this->_href . $symbol . "___store=" . $store->getCode();
```

into:

```
$this->_href = $this->_href;
```

in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Widget/Link.php`

But didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not remove it from the phtml file for the store/language switcher? Magento does however use this variable tho so it could have negative side effects to remove it

Comment: What does your address bar say in your browser. Is it also extended by the storecode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not keep it simple.

Instead of making new module etc just remove last part of your string containing `?___store=en_ca`

```
<?php foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {

            // check if $url contain ?, if yes then strip last part of url
            $url = $store->getCurrentUrl(false); 
            if((strpos($url, '?') !== false)){ 
                $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, "?"));
            }

            $storeCode = $store->getCode(); // addad url as variable
            echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $storeCode . '" href="' . $url . '"/>' . "\n";
        }
    } } ?>
```

Comment: now the url link not contain  ___store=en_ca.but store switcher not working

Answer (score 0):

You can change this setting in the admin area by going to System -> Configuration -> Web (under General) and it is in the Url Options tab.

Comment: If you mean "Add Store Code to Urls", then I have that set as No.

Comment: @Smartie then the url shows store code. how to remove both store code and ?___store from url

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](http://www.programdevelop.com/4855850/).

Copy app/code/core/mage/core/model/store.php to app/code/local/mage/core/model/store.php and

change from

```
return $storeParsedUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $storeParsedUrl['host']
            . (isset($storeParsedUrl['port']) ? ':' . $storeParsedUrl['port'] : '')
            . $storeParsedUrl['path'] . $requestString
            . ($storeParsedQuery ? '?'.http_build_query($storeParsedQuery, '', '&amp;') : '');
```

to

```
return $storeParsedUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $storeParsedUrl['host']
            . (isset($storeParsedUrl['port']) ? ':' . $storeParsedUrl['port'] : '')
            . $storeParsedUrl['path'] . $requestString;
```

So, remove  **. ($storeParsedQuery ? '?'.http_build_query($storeParsedQuery, '', '&') : '')**

Comment: Even IF it required you to modify a core model class this is not the way to do it. You should use rewrites instead of just copying the file in to the local code pool.

Comment: How can I do that? I have this issue only with the URL output of hreflang link in <head>. I don't have this issue with the pages of the store (eg, product page etc.)

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/ is a good article

Comment: now the url link not contain ___store=en_ca.but store switcher not working